# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'. when deploying a Streamlit app

Tags: heroku, pickle, streamlit

```
2021-12-24T08:53:38.861552+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-12-24 08:53:38.861 Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-24T08:53:38.861560+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
2021-12-24T08:53:38.861561+00:00 app[web.1]:     exec(code, module.__dict__)
2021-12-24T08:53:38.861562+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 10, in <module>
2021-12-24T08:53:38.861562+00:00 app[web.1]:     similar = pickle.load(open('similar.pkl', 'rb'))
2021-12-24T08:53:38.861563+00:00 app[web.1]: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'.
```

I've used git lfs to push the similar.pkl data, it is showing correct output in my localhost but giving me error when deploying code on heroku. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for Git-LFS in Heroku so git-lfs is not installed in your heroku environment.

Because you used Git-LFS to push .pickle files to your remote repo this is causing the error.

The solution is to install Git-LFS on your Heroku environment.

There are a lot of explanations how to do it here is one [Heroku buildpack for git-lfs](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/raxod502/heroku-buildpack-git-lfs)